# What are the best MTB Tennis Shoes ? (without clippers)

Tags: mountain-bike, shoes

Can anyone recommend any type of tennis shoe that could help me not to slip while on my mountain bike but without having to use clippers. The thing about clippers is that I hate not having enough time to react when I´m close or about to fall.

Comment: By clippers, do you mean pedal/cleat systems ([SPD](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/mtb1/pedals/pedals.html)s) or [toe straps](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=toe+strap+pedals&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)? What model of pedals do you currently have, as they'll have some bearing on how grippy you'll be able to get. E.g. if they're very flat and smooth you'll only ever get so much grip regardless of what shoes you use.

Comment: There are clip systems with adjustable release so very light force is needed to get out. Plus, it becomes second nature to unclip. If you really want flat pedals, you can try ones with studs to help you grip along with a shoe that doesn't slip much.

Comment: My impression (not being a mountain biker myself) is that the serious MB users tend to favor hiking shoes, if they're not using toe straps or cleats.

Comment: Premise of question is wrong - best MTB shoes are not Tennis shoes, they are MTB shoes. Some MTB shoes are designed to look like other (street, skate and  sports) shoes, and are easily mistaken for sports shoes. If foot slipping off the pedals are the likely the problem, not the shoes.  Get good flats and any shoe will stick to them.

Comment: @mattnz in many languages, "tennis shoe" means any generic sports shoe or street shoe that looks like one. "Iker Quintana" doesn't sound like a native English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for shoes with as soft outsole as possible. Ones specially made for cycling are available from bike stores, labeled "downhill mtb shoes". Skateboard shoes and approach shoes from climbing department also work well, choose one that fits your style.

Answer (score 0):

You could try grip tape on the pedals (skateboard shop). I use hiking boots.I don't like sand and dirt in shoes Still slippery when wet. Deck shoes for sailing is another option. They are supposed to grip even when wet.